# Missing Microsoft.Azure.Websites service principal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I’m trying to get a certificate for my App Service I’m deploying from Key Vault using this template (https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/webapp-keyvault-ssl).  Part of this requires creating a Key Vault access policy which grants the Microsoft.Azure.Websites service principal (ID abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd) get on the Secrets.  This works in my subscription just fine, but wasn’t working in the customer’s subscription.  We could run the Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy command referencing the service principal’s ID, and it executed without error, but the access policy does not actually get created.  When I did a get-azAdServicePrincipal -DisplayNameBeginsWith ‘Microsoft.Azure.Websites’ nothing is returned.  Yet when I look in the audit log for the KeyVault I can see a user with ID abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd trying to log in, so somewhere this identity must exist(?)

Is there something I need to do to enable/create this default (Microsoft.Azure.Websites) service principal?  I checked my MSDN account and see the same behavior, in that this principal is not present.

Can deploy this template in a subscription where the Microsoft.Azure.Websites principal exists, but when the principal does not exist, the template deployment will fail.

```bsh
#Gets the service principal (missing in problem subscription)
get-azAdServicePrincipal -DisplayNameBeginsWith 'Microsoft.Azure.Websites'

#Sets the keyvault access policy for the built in service principal
set-azKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName keyVaultName -ServicePrincipalName "abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd" -PermissionsToSecrets get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`‘abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd’` is the Resource Provider service principal name and it remains **same for all Azure subscriptions.** And its display name in service principal is 'Microsoft Azure App Service', not 'Microsoft.Azure.Websites'.

Try with

```
Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd
```

to see if it exists.

If it doesn't exist, check the resource provider of your subscription.

Comment: Thanks - the display name in my subscription is "Microsoft.Azure.Websites", so I am wondering if it was changed at some point (and several articles, e.g. https://winterdom.com/2017/08/29/webapp-with-keyvault-cert-and-sql-token-auth show this).  At any rate, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

To fix - add the SPN to your AAD Tenant like they show for the Front Door in their docs; see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain-https#azure-powershell
but be sure to swap the guid in their example with 'abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).